# Elasticsearch Java API - Bool Query Operator

Tags: java, elasticsearch, boolean

I am using Elasticsearch 2.4.3 in my Spring Boot App and use following Query

```
    QueryBuilder qb = new BoolQueryBuilder()
        .must(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(term, "phoneticFirstName", "phoneticLastName", "phoneticLocationName", "phoneticCompanyName")
                .analyzer("atsCustomSearchAnalyzer")
                .operator(Operator.AND))
        .must(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(term, "ngramFirstName^3", "ngramLastName^3", "ngramLocationName^3", "ngramCompanyName^3", "_all")
                .analyzer("atsCustomSearchAnalyzer")
                .operator(Operator.AND));
```

I want to get a response, where the first Query or the second Query get hits.... can you help me to change that in my Code, please?

**UPDATE**

```
        "atsCustomPhoneticAnalyzer":{
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer":"whitespace",
            "filter":["lowercase","asciifolding","atsPhoneticFilter"]
        },
        "atsCustomSearchAnalyzer":{
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer":"whitespace",
            "filter":["lowercase","asciifolding","umlautStemmer","germanStemmer"]   
        }
```

**UPDATE #2**

```
    QueryBuilder qb = new BoolQueryBuilder()
        .should(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(term, "ngramFirstName", "ngramLastName", "ngramLocationName", "ngramCompanyName")
            .type(Type.CROSS_FIELDS)
            .analyzer("atsCustomSearchAnalyzer")
            .operator(Operator.AND)
            .boost(3))
        .should(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(term, "phoneticLastName")
            .analyzer("atsCustomPhoneticAnalyzer")
            .operator(Operator.AND))
        .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(term, "_all")
                .analyzer("atsCustomSearchAnalyzer")
                .operator(Operator.AND))
        .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1);
```

I have 2 indices: persons and activities. When I comment out the second query I get Hits from persons and activities. If all 3 queries are present the hits from activities are not there anymore....

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `must` with `should` instead and add `minimumShouldMatch(1)`

Comment: Thanks Val, it works! But my Koelnerphonetic Query will not work :( it handles such things like "Mayer / Maier / Meyer / Meier" and say that these ones are sounds same ... in my question I've updated my Mapping/Setting for this

Comment: Ok, nvm ..... I just used the wrong analyzer in the first query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change `must` with `should` instead and add `minimumShouldMatch(1)`

```
QueryBuilder qb = new BoolQueryBuilder()
    .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1)
    .should(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(term, "phoneticFirstName", "phoneticLastName", "phoneticLocationName", "phoneticCompanyName")
            .analyzer("atsCustomSearchAnalyzer")
            .operator(Operator.AND))
    .should(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(term, "ngramFirstName^3", "ngramLastName^3", "ngramLocationName^3", "ngramCompanyName^3", "_all")
            .analyzer("atsCustomSearchAnalyzer")
            .operator(Operator.AND));
```

Comment: Thanks for the example - it worked! But now I've got another problem (see question Update #2)

Comment: You need to use the correct analyzer, you have defined `atsCustomPhoneticAnalyzer` but you're referencing `atsCustomSearchAnalyzer`

Comment: Added my CustomSearchAnalyzer to my mapping example in Question area

Comment: Look at the names of the analyzers, they don't match with the one you're using in your query.

Comment: Have I any write errors in my settings? I don't see any matching problems

Comment: Without the second query with the phoneticanalyzer I recieve Hits from both indices (persons and activities). With the phoneticanalyzer-query I only recieve hits from persons and not from activities anymore

Comment: Ok, now you've fixed it. I'd say that this new issue would warrant another question, the initial one being solved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982723/elasticsearch-java-api-wrong-hits-with-bool-query

Comment: Just added a new Question and linked it here - hope you can help me one more time :)